# Realizar una consulta en SQL evitando multiplicidad

Tags: sql, informix

Tengo una tabla `Producto` y una tabla `Proveedor` (se relacionan por el `campoidProducto`).

En este caso en particular quiero un *query* que resulte todos los productos, y por cada producto mostrar un proveedor (un producto puede tener varios proveedores, solo se necesita mostrar uno ya que es para una visualización de productos).

Comment: Hola user47431, bienvenido a [es.so], para poder ayudarte con el problema que presentas es necesario conocer más detalles como estructuras de tablas, intentos que has hecho. Ayúdanos a ayudarte, mientras tanto tu pregunta puede ser cerrada por estar demasiado amplia o basarse en opiniones, recuerda que este sitio trata de problemas concretos y por lo tanto se dan respuestas concretas :D

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM TABLA_PRODUCTOS P INNER JOIN TABLA_PROVEEDORES PR ON PR.IDPRODUCTO = P.IDPRODUCTO GROUP BY IDPRODUCTO.

Esta sería la forma. Es aconsejable mostrar las pruebas que hayas hecho con el código y dar más información de las tablas, como el campo común con el que hacer el INNER JOIN.